# Multiple tables query android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have three tables

```
 Article            Group            Code
 --------          --------        --------
   id                id              id
  Name             GroupName       CodeName    
  NameInfo        Group value     code value
   Bla
   bla
 groupname
 codename
  something
   bla
```

Can you please tell me how to make table so that I can see in my first table named articles values groupname and codename from another table? And then how to make select query?

Comment: You can use DAO http://greendao-orm.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create relational database structure,

[image]

```
select * from Article a 
inner join Group g on  (a.groupid = g.groupid)
inner join Code c on (a.codeid = c.codeid)
```

Comment: it compiles it, and im using cursor to get data, in the table groupid i get only id, not group name, and its same for code, any idea?... btw. tnx for help, my previous code didn't even wan't to compile

Comment: it works, it was about my cursor, i didn't know that those join commands means that he adds more columns to output table... your help means lot!! :) :)